# finding implicit representation of 2D plane

Tags: math, graphics, geometry, plane

I want to find the implicit representation of a 2D plane that is tangent to the sphere S at point (4,3,4),
where S: (x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 + z^2 - 26 = **0**

How can I find it?

Answer (score 3):

Sphere equation

```
(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 + z^2 - 26 = 0
```

denotes that center has coordinates

```
C = (1, 2, 0)
```

and radius-vector to point `P=(4,3,4)` is

```
N = P - C = (3, 1, 4)
```

This vector is normal to the plane, so plane equation is

```
3*x + 1*y + 4*z  + d  = 0
```

Substitute known point `P` into equation to get `d` coefficient:

```
d = - (3*4 + 3 + 4*4) = -31
```

Finally plane equation is

```
3x + y + 4z - 31 = 0
```

P.S. I believe that using term **2D** plane is random error